# github pages missing path

Tags: github-pages, relative-path

In my github repo exists a folder within the pathway "TriviaGame/assets/images/" but on the io page of that repo, the pathway to the file produces a "404". It seems that github pages is not uploading the image. ["TriviaGame/assets/images/backgroundimage.png"][1]

TriviaGame/assets/images/backgroundImage.png
https://dboothy.github.io/TriviaGame/assets/images/backgroundimage.png

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

dboothy.github.io/:1 GET https://dboothy.github.io/TriviaGame/assets/images/backgroundimage.png 404

[404 error on io](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKKvl.png)

[1]:

```css
.content-wrap {
 background: url("../images/backgroundimage.png") no-repeat center fixed;
 background-size: cover;
 min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-wrap" align="center">
<div id="heading" class="hide">
  <h2>Time remaining: <span id="timer"></span></h2>
 </div>
 <div class= "container">
  <div id = "game-wrapper">
    <div id="main-content">
     <div class="content-container">
      <h1>Movie Trivia</h1>
      <div id="welcome">
       <p>try and answer as many question in the time allowed</p>
       <div id="results" class="hide"></div>
       <button id="startGame" class="textBox">Start</button>
      </div>
      <div id="gameWrap" class="hide">
       <div id="questionWrap"></div>
       <button id="finish" class="btn btn-warning">FINISH</button>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7kG8.png

Answer (score 0):

In css above I typed:
"../images/backgroundimage.png"

when actually file was named "../images/backgroundImage.png"